# Grant a JIRA user read-only access to user-browser

Tags: permissions, jira

I need to create a Jira user/role for our support team to be able to login to JIRA and see what groups a user belongs to.  They don't need to be able to edit or change anything, this should be read only, and ideally they would only access the user-browser.  Jira 3.13.2 with Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing who is in a group in JIRA is only allowed for members of jira-administrators. JIRA recommends using JIRA project roles rather than groups because they can be seen in more places and modified by project administrators.

If you really need this then I'd pursue custom development to change which groups are show for a user in their profile. It looks like the original three jira-* groups are shown to everyone but not groups that were added.

Comment: Or tweak the source of GroupPermissionCheckerImpl in the hasViewGroupPermission method